# Can PidTagSearchKey be used to map an old ItemId to new ItemId when a contact is moved to different folder using EWS managed api?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm doing a bulk move of contacts to a different folder.
I know I can move each contact one by one to get the new ItemId after moving. But that'd be expensive in terms of number of EWS calls.

> This property provides a trace for related objects, such as message copies, and facilitates finding unwanted occurrences, such as duplicate recipients.

Above lines are from this [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc815908.aspx). But I don't know if I can assume the following from that:

- Can I assume no two contacts will have PidTagSearchKey the same if it is just moved from one folder to another?

If not, is there any other way I can bulk move contacts and still get the new ItemIds using less number of EWS calls than moving contacts one by one?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out that I cannot use PidTagSeachKey because if someone has copied a contact and edited the 2nd one to make it a different contact, both will have the same PidTagSeachKey.